# Update flag based on max last updated date within in the group

Tags: postgresql, update, greatest-n-per-group

Say for example I have three records:

```
Name          Email          Group ID      Last update date     Master Record
dinesh.s    dinesh.s@xyz.com    10              1 Apr 2019  
dinesh.s    dinesh.s@xyz.com    10              7 Feb 2019  
dinesh.s    dinesh.s@xyz.com    10              20 Nov 2019
```

The three record are exact matches with email so we consider they all belong to one group (Group ID).

I need to update in master record columns AS 'Y' based on frequently updated record, in this example we need to update 'Y' as below:

```
Name          Email          Group ID      Last update date     Master Record
dinesh.s    dinesh.s@xyz.com    10              1 Apr 2019  
dinesh.s    dinesh.s@xyz.com    10              7 Feb 2019  
dinesh.s    dinesh.s@xyz.com    10              20 Nov 2019         Y
```

Can you please help me to write a query for this in Postgres?

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `MAX()` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-select

```
update the_table
  set master_record = 'Y'
where (name, email, last_update_date) = (select name, email, max(last_update_date)
                                         from the_table
                                         group by name, email);
```

Another option would be to use a derived table, which might be faster:

```
update the_table
  set master_record = 'Y'
from (
  select name, email, max(last_update_date) as max_date
  from the_table
  group by name, email
) t
where t.name = the_table.name
  and t.email = the_table.email
  and t.max_date = the_table.last_update_date;
```

Both statements assume that the combination `(name, email, last_update_date)` is unique.

Comment: Is this possible to get the same in the select statement itself?

Comment: Sure, but why did you ask for an UPDATE then?

Comment: Why might it be faster?